# Find sum of nodes height in a binary tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

How to find sum of node's height in a binary tree recursively?

Example:

[image]

```
public int totalHeight() {
    return totalHeight(root);
}

private int totalHeight(BinaryNode<AnyType> n) {

    int totalHeight = 0;

    if (n.left == null && n.right == null)
        return totalHeight;
    if (n.left != null && n.right != null)
        return totalHeight + 1
                + Math.max(totalHeight(n.left), totalHeight(n.right));
    if (n.left != null)
        return totalHeight + 1 + Math.max(totalHeight(n.left), -1);
    if (n.right != null)
        return totalHeight + 1 + Math.max(-1, totalHeight(n.right));

    return totalHeight;
}
```

I have tried this, but it only get the height of the tree instead of sum of all node's height.

I feel difficult to track the counter in recursion, it seems that the `totalHeight` set to 0 every recursive call. This is not good.

Comment: This method gives you the height of a single node. What if you'd create another function where you'd apply it to every node in the tree and add the results?  This would be O(n^2*log n)  (which is bad) but will work.

Comment: Use a global variable to keep track of the total.

Answer (score 1):

A simple version would be to do a two-pass process where you first record for each node the height it is at, and then iterate through the nodes to sum them up. This method can be made recursive, but it is easy to do it in just one pass by summing as you calculate the height.

```
public static int totalHeightSum = 0;

private int calculateHeightAndAdd ( Node n )
{
     if ( n == null )
        return 0;

     int leftHeight = calculateHeightAndAdd ( n.left );
     int rightHeight= calculateHeightAndAdd ( n.right);

     int myHeight = 1 + Math.max ( leftHeight, rightHeight );

     totalHeightSum += myHeight;

     return myHeight;
}
```

Comment: if ( n == null )
        return 0; Instead of return 0 ,-1 should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Recurcively find height of each node and keep adding to a static variable. Alternately, you could memorize the height and store in each node and then do another recursion to add them up.

The recursion should return the height of the node n and not the total heights of each of the nodes in the subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Given your implementation of the height of a node, let's simply call it `height(BinaryNode<?>)`, you can:

if you have access to all the nodes in a collection:

```
int sumHeight(List<BinaryNode<?>> nodes) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (BinaryNode<?> node: nodes) {
        sum += height(node);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

if you only have access to the nodes in a tree structure:

```
int sumHeight(BinaryNode<?> node) {
    if (node == null) return 0;
    return height(node) + sumHeight(node.left) + sumHeight(node.right);
}
```

It would be interesting to see if there're algo's that can do the calculation in one recursion (maybe some backtracking algo?).

Comment: No need for backtracking algorithm; just store the height in a map as it's being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have come out a solution.

a) if `n == null` return `0`

b) if `n.left == null && n.right == null` return `0`

c) the total height is `total height of left` + `total height of right` + `the height of it self`

- the height of itself is:

1) if left side is larger, then total height of left minus total height of left's left

2) if right side is larger, then total height of right minus total height of right's right

```
public int totalHeight() {
    return totalHeight(root);
}

private int totalHeight(BinaryNode<AnyType> n) {
    if (n == null)
        return 0;
    else if (n.left == null && n.right == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return totalHeight(n.left)
                + totalHeight(n.right)
                + (totalHeight(n.left) > totalHeight(n.right) ? totalHeight(n.left)
                        - (n.left == null ? 0 : totalHeight(n.left.left))
                        : totalHeight(n.right)
                                - (n.right == null ? 0
                                        : totalHeight(n.right.right))) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not updating heights during insertion.

Solution:
I would traverse through the tree in a inorder way. So I first declare root.height=0.

And then say

```
BinaryNode right;
BinaryNode left;
BinaryNode parent;
static int level;
int height;


if(left!=null)
{
    left.height=left.parent.height+1;
    level=level+left.height;
    left.yourMethod();
}

if(right!=null)
{
    right.height= right.parent.height+1; 
    level=level+right.height;
    right.yourMethod();
}
```

So you will now have level that stores all the heights.

Alternative method can be Breadth first search traversal using a queue, but the answer would be the same.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

void addHeights(class tree* root, int depth, int& sum)
{
    if(root)
    {
        addHeights(root->left, depth+1, sum);
        addHeights(root->right, depth+1, sum);
        sum += depth;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public int sum(){
    return sum(root);
}
private int sum(BinaryNode <?> n){
    if(n == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return n.data + sum(n.left) + sum(n.right);

}
```

I need more data to assess your code though I am assuming that you called the data inside the node "data".

So if the node is null it means you have reached the end of the tree and returns 0. Otherwise it takes the data and traverses towards the left then to the right. With each recursion they are being added until they are no more nodes left to be added.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private  int maxHeight(BinaryNode<AnyType> n) {
  if (n ! = null) return 0;
  int leftheight = maxHeight(n.left);
   int rightheight = maxHeight(n.right);
  return (leftheight > rightheight) ? leftheight + 1 : rightheight + 1;
}
```

So far you have known the 4 cases to count the height

The essence is to continue to go left or right node if the left child or the right child exist.
if exist, return 1.

The counting function goes in the last statement. That is to get the largest height counted.

The main course is to get familiar with recursion and the programming stack  when the method is working.

Comment: I think you have misunderstand my question, I want to have the sum of all node's height instead of finding the tree's height.

Comment: how about inputting the parameters as left child , right child and then add all the height result?